# Autocomplete suggestions for dynamically generated JavaScript methods (JetBrains)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jetbrains-ide

I'm building a decoupled Drupal site with Vue+TypeScript (using PhpStorm as my IDE), and am building some getter methods to hit endpoints based on https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/commerce-api/about-the-api#s-resource-type-alterations. I'm defining the array of endpoints like this:

```
/**
 * Endpoints modified/provided by commerce_api module.
 *
 * @see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/commerce-api/about-the-api
 * @param type - Used in the resourcePath if needed.
 */
const endpointsFromCommerceApi = (type?: string): EndpointDefinition[] => ([
  {
    entityType: 'commerce_checkout_flow',
    resourceTypeName: 'checkout-flow',
    resourcePath: `/${prefix}/checkout-flows`,
    usesType: false
  },
  {
    entityType: 'commerce_store',
    resourceTypeName: `store--${type}`,
    resourcePath: `/${prefix}/stores/${type}`,
    usesType: true
  },
  ...
])
```

It's a hassle to write out and maintain all of those getters manually so I'm generating them with this:

```
/**
 * Creates getter methods for all commerce_api endpoint definitions.
 */
const constructGetters = () => endpointsFromCommerceApi().reduce((getters, ed) => {
  const methodName = stringUtils.toCamel(`get_${ed.entityType.replace('commerce_', '')}`);

  return {
    ...getters,
    [methodName]: !ed.usesType
      ? async () => await axiosJsonApi.get<JsonResponse<any>>(`https://mysite.ddev.site/${ed.resourcePath}`)
      : (() => async (type: string) => {
        const endpoint = getEndpointDefinition(ed.resourceTypeName, type)
        return await axiosJsonApi.get<JsonResponse<any>>(`https://mysite.ddev.site/${endpoint.resourcePath}`);
      })()
  }
}, {});
```

...which returns an object that looks something like:

```
{
  getCheckoutFlow: async () => { ... },
  getStore: async (type: string) => { ... }
}
```

And then exporting them for use around the app with:

```
export const useCommerceApi = () => ({
  getEndpoint: getEndpointDefinition, // defined elsewhere in the file.
  ...constructGetters()
})
```

The issue is that when I import and implement `useCommerceApi` elsewhere, the only method that's provided as a suggestion is `getEndpoint`. Is there any way to get the IDE to understand which methods are available via `...constructGetters()`? Fwiw, I'm open to the idea that this is just a bad way to go about this, too.

Comment: No, the IDE is analyzing the code statically to provide the completion, there is no way to have the methods that only exist in runtime offered in completion (unless you add JSDoc annotations describing the generated object to your code - but that's, again, a manual work)

Comment: Thanks @lena, thought that was the case but wanted to make sure.